# React: deployment with serve in production mode

Tags: reactjs, serve

I have an reactjs application that I have deploy on my web server.

I build my app (So it's create a `build` folder) and when I want to start it with `~/.npm-packages/bin/serve -s ./build -l tcp://0.0.0.0:8100` it work (with work dir set to `react/`, build is here `react/build` but we can see all source code on my page, that theory not possible in production mode.

If I set the work dir to `react/build` it return a 404 error.

[image]

Inside `build` folder

[image: Inside build]

It doesn't return any other error unfortunately.

Update: I only stock `build` folder and it work, but we can always see source code even its in production mode.

If I change to `react/build`, `react/build/static` or other, it display 404.

Comment: Since you are trying to deploy on production,I would rather suggest using `pm2` along with `serve` to fulfill your purpose.
You can find a  details about how to deploy using pm2 here in the link https://www.loginradius.com/engineering/blog/react-app-deployment/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using [npm's serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) (the default for create-react-app, which I am assuming you are using), that second argument is the directory to serve:

```
$ serve --help

$ serve} [-l listen_uri [-l ...]] [directory]

By default, serve will listen on 0.0.0.0:5000 and serve the
current working directory on that address.

-s, --single                        Rewrite all not-found requests to `index.html`
```

But serve is meant for development serving. It works fine for production of a small static site, but consider another production-proven web server.

Your unminified source should not be kept on a production server, at all. You should deploy just the build files to production.

Comment: Finally I have remove the option `-s ./build` and it work

Comment: `-s` and `./build` are two different options, not one: `-s` is to redirect 404s to an index.html file, and the directory is the base path to serve. Without the optional directory, it serves the present working directory -- which appears to be the problem you had.